# CSS properties gone when saving summernote's content

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, summernote

I am using summernote as my WYSIWYG editor. So I have submitted its contents through ajax using formdata. I've done the following:

```
 formdata.append('content', $('.summernote').code());
```

So my PHP accepted it and save into my database. However, all css properties were gone upon saving like font style and font sizes etc. I am using CodeIgniter in my php and this is my code in saving:

```
     public function save_spot_report($data){
            $to_return = true;

            $this->db->trans_begin();
            $this->save_spot_report_details($data);
            if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){
                $this->db->trans_rollback();
                $array['error_message'] = $this->db->_error_message();
                $array['error_number'] = $this->db->_error_number();
                $to_return = $array;     
            }else{  
                $this->db->trans_commit();

            }

            return $to_return;
        }

        public function save_spot_report_details($data){
            $this->load->library('DateTimeHelper');
            $data['created_by'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
            $data['date'] = $this->datetimehelper->get_current_date();

            $config['table'] = 'spot_report_tbl';
            $config['data'] = $data;

            $this->special_save($config);

        }
public function special_save($config){

            if(!isset($config['type'])){
                $config['type'] = "INSERT";
            }
            if(strtolower($config['type']) === "insert"){
                $this->db->insert($config['table'],$config['data']);
            }else{
                $this->db->where($config['conditions']);
                if(!isset($config['use_set'])){
                    $this->db->update($config['table'], $config['data']);
                }else{
                    $params = $config['set_params'];
                    $this->db->set($params['param_1'], $params['param_2'], $params['param_3']);
                    $this->db->update($config['table']);
                }

            }
            return $this->check();
        }
```

Your responses will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If you go and look at the table containing the data does it still contain the HTML markup correct with all of the styling? It may have slashes etc to escape but that's fine. If all looks well there how does the markup look when you 'view-source' on the output webpage?